# cyclotomic polynomials of given degree

Tags: nt.number-theory, computational-complexity

Is there a fast algorithm to generate all cyclotomic polynomials $\Phi_n$ for which the degree of $\Phi_n$ is a fixed constant $d?$ This is obviously related to the "inverse totient" function: compute all $n$ for which $\phi(n) = d.$

Comment: This http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0404116v3.pdf  paper of Contini, Croot and Shparlinki produces a polynomial time algorithm to compute $n$ for "almost all d" (the authors also give complexity for all $d.$)

Comment: Do you want to *write down* those cyclotomic polynomials ? Because if you do, then the complexity is at least proportional do $d$. So you might as well use an explicit lower bound on $\phi(n)$, and use it to list all the possible $n$ and compute all of their $\phi(n)$ with a sieve, which will be $d^{1+o(1)}$.